# Use ModelBuilder to project rasters from 600 folders into subfolders in each folder

Tags: coordinate-system, arcmap, modelbuilder, loop, workspace

I have 600 folders, each folder contains a raster (IMG) and I want to project each raster from one coordinate system to another and  generate new folder in the source folder to contain the projected raster output result by using ModelBuilder.

[image]

Comment: What happened when you ran the model that you’ve presented?